# Archunit matching on a constructor for a generic type

Tags: java, generics, archunit

I want to make an ArchUnit rule that picks up calls to [Spring's ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) that look like this:

```
new ResponseEntity<>("No record", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

I tried a rule like this:

```
    ArchRule rule = noClasses().should().
        callConstructor(ResponseEntity.class, String.class, HttpStatus.class).
        because("foo");
```

but it doesn't seem to be match. My guess at the moment is that this is because of the generic type, as I changing the rule to target a non-generic type and that seemed to work.

I have a feeling that using `callConstructorWhere()` might be part of the solution but I'm struggling to find an example of how to use that and can't seem to find the right part of the documentation. I'm using ArchUnit 0.23.1.

Comment: I got the same issue. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct: The generic constructor `ResponseEntity(T, HttpStatus)` has [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) parameter types `(Object, HttpStatus)`,¹ and [`callConstructor`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.23.1/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#callConstructor(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class...)) looks for these raw types.

Unfortunately, even if you use [`callConstructorWhere`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.23.1/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#callConstructorWhere(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)) with a custom predicate for the [`JavaConstructorCall`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.23.1/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaConstructorCall.html), you can only get access to the [target owner](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.23.1/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/AccessTarget.html#getOwner()) as (raw) `JavaClass`, but not as [`JavaParameterizedType`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.23.1/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaParameterizedType.html) that could hold the specific type argument `T = String` in your case.

So I fear that your issue cannot be solved with the current version of ArchUnit.

---

¹ With your `spring-web.jar` at hand, you can investigate this using

```bash
jar xf spring-web-*.jar

javap -v org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.class \
| grep -A1 'ResponseEntity(T, org.springframework.http.HttpStatus)'
```

For [`spring-web-5.3.22.jar`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.3.22/jar), I get:

```
  public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity(T, org.springframework.http.HttpStatus);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/http/HttpStatus;)V
```

Comment: Ah - that makes sense, thank you for the explanation! I'd not understood that ArchUnit is looking at the types of the method being called, rather than the types of the parameters that are being passed. Do you think this is the kind of thing ArchUnit might support in the future?